# Sahi OS : Version 4.4 : facing issues with Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, sahi

I was trying to run my script from Chrome browser by using SAHI OS tool, but finding difficulty in running them.

I ran the test successfully only once in 20-30 times and again coming across the issues like `'Page(s) not responsive on controller'` / the https login page is just loading and not proceeding to further steps.

The envt am using is below:

```
Sahi OS v4.4
Google Chrome Version - Version 33.0.1750.154 m
Jdk1.6
```

Your help in resolving the issue would be a great.

Thanks,
-Anil

Answer (score 0):

You can try to see if there are any openXHRs that are blocking the execution and leading to timeout. You can try this on controller:

' _sahi.areWindowsLoaded()='+_sahi.areWindowsLoaded() + '\n' + 
'_sahi.areXHRsDone()='+_sahi.areXHRsDone() + '\n' + 
'_sahi.showOpenXHRs()='+_sahi.showOpenXHRs() + '\n\n\n' + 
'--\nIf you see a lot of XHRs open in readyState 1, add \n' +
'_setXHRReadyStatesToWaitFor("2,3") \n at the start of your script or *before* the step after which Sahi hangs.'.replace(/*sahi[.]*/g, '_')

This is a copy paste from the pro version diagnose. Since I am not an open source user, I am not sure if all the functionality mention here is present in OS. But I believe you will be able to figure out after looking at these statements.